# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bdd, specflow

This is my feature file

```
Given site is opened
Then I Close the modal
Then Find your restaurant page displays
When I select a restaurant name
Then The selected restaurant page displays
When I click "Go" button
```

I’m totally new to automation testing with bdd using selenium webdriver. I wanted to book a table in a restaurant .When I execute my project I see only first three steps other steps not working and Not selecting the restaurant as well. To select a restaurant I have used SelectByIndex(3) method. I get the below error.  Could anyone please help me to rectify this issue?

[image: Error Message]

This is the code I have given in my WebDriverExtensions.cs file

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KflLp.png

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SKBy.png)

I wanted to book a table in a restaurant

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please do not post images or code or errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include a [repro] with code formatted as text using the `{ }` icon in the question editor. Furthermore, please include the error message and stack trace as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue here is one of clarity; Your question omits the code you're using (you mention the method but don't demonstrate it's use), there's no logical `Then` statement to Assert the end result, and the order of your BDD scenarios is generally unclear.

Due to the lack of information, I can only suggest a change to your BDD scenario syntax to improve the readability of your test. If you want help with the error, I would suggest adding your code in full to the comments or amend your question (please use StackOverflow's formatting tools).

**Test Readability - Good Practice:**

It's good practice to keep tests short and snappy, in both execution and for readability. Well structured scenarios should ideally have one `Given`, followed by one `When` followed by one `Then`, usually in that order. You can also make use of `And` and `But`.

E.g.

```
Given this is where we start
When I do a thing
Then this is the outcome
```

Here's your scenario:

```
Given site is opened 
Then I Close the modal [enter image description here][1]
Then Find your restaurant page displays 
When I select a restaurant name 
Then The selected restaurant page displays 
When I click "Go" button
```

There's a lot of set-up there so it'd benefit from a shared background, and there's no ending `Then` statement. How you could re-structure it:

```
Background:
Given the site is open
And the modal has been closed
And the Find your Restaurant page is displayed

Scenario: I can book a table
When I select a restaurant name
And the selected restaurant page displays
When I book a table
Then the success page is displayed
```

Assuming you're using a SpecFlow / Page Object Model approach, each of those steps creates a Step Definition which, in turn, look at the methods to complete each step. The background can also be used for any other test in the same feature file beginning at the Find your Restaurant page, so you don't need to duplicate those lines.

You could further condense it for readability and just include the necessary methods in fewer step definitions:

```
Scenario: I can book a table
When I select a restaurant name
And I book a table at a selected restaurant
Then the success page is displayed
```

If you add comments to your Assertions, you'll still know at what point the test fails.

Making your tests readable, short and snappy will mean you can maintain them better down the line.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have put detailed info in another thread. Hope it's more understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74532253/timed-out-after-10-seconds